# Font size small medium and large according to theme selected

Tags: css, angularjs, themes

I am using angularjs I need to create theme for application.

I am getting themeSize "S" for small "M" for medium and "L" for large
if I choose S everything need to be small like 
h1 should have 14 then p should have 10 others subheader should be 12.
Similarly if I choose "L" then 
all the header should become 20px then sub-header should become 16px and contents 14px.

Also I have  at top of page that color and other sub elements should also be change when I am choosing other theme.

Comment: i think you can acheive this by setting a class to your body and then making the proper CSS rules for all your DOM elements needing font change, no need for angular.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more.. or plnkr would be great help

Comment: When you get the value 'S', 'L', ect, set a class to your body in html. Then in your css file, make css rules that start off with that class.

Recieve 'M', Append class theme-M to body.

Have css rules as such:
`.theme-M h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
}`